# 2 FOREIGN KEYS to the same PRIMARY KEY

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am having problem when creating FOREIGN KEY for two of my tables (Characters) and (Factions).

Let me explain the situation:

A character normally have a faction but some can have 2, so (Characters) tabel have two columns [Faction1] and [Faction2] both must be related with the (Factions) table. So I made a FOREIGN KEY (FK_Charachters(1)_Factions) with
Set Null on delete
Cascade on update

When I tried to make the FOREIGN KEY (FK_Charachters(2)_Factions) that will use the column [Faction2] instead of [Faction1] as the previous key and also make 
Set Null on delete
Cascade on update

I get the error message:

"Unable to create relationship 'FK_Characters(2)_Factions'.
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Characters(2)_Factions' on table 'Characters' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints."

And of course when I set ON DELETE NO ACTION and ON UPDATE NO ACTION everything works fine but that will prevent any update for the faction.

What can I do to enforce those 2 FOREIGN KEY ?

~TIA~
(Characters) Table

```
    USE [HDA]
    GO

    /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Characters]    Script Date: 05/15/2014 02:38:19 ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO

    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Characters](
        [ID] [smallint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [CODE] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
        [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
        [NameID] [smallint] NULL,
        [Tier] [tinyint] NULL,
        [Grp1] [tinyint] NULL,
        [Grp2] [tinyint] NULL,
        [Rarity] [tinyint] NULL,
        [Fac1] [tinyint] NULL,
        [Fac2] [tinyint] NULL,
        [Speciality] [tinyint] NULL,
        [MaxLevel] [smallint] NULL,
        [Power] [smallint] NULL,
        [HP] [smallint] NULL,
        [Speed] [tinyint] NULL,
        [Attack] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
        [AttackDesc] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
        [PowerPerLevel] [tinyint] NULL,
        [HPPerLevel] [tinyint] NULL,
        [TS] [timestamp] NULL,
        [CreationDate] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_Characters] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [ID] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Characters]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Characters_AttackDescription] FOREIGN KEY([AttackDesc])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[AttackDescription] ([ID])
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Characters] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Characters_AttackDescription]
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Characters]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Characters_CharactersName] FOREIGN KEY([NameID])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[CharactersName] ([ID])
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ON DELETE SET NULL
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Characters] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Characters_CharactersName]
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Characters]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Characters_Rarity] FOREIGN KEY([Rarity])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Rarity] ([ID])
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ON DELETE SET NULL
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Characters] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Characters_Rarity]
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Characters] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__Character__Creat__395884C4]  DEFAULT (sysdatetime()) FOR [CreationDate]
    GO
```

(Factions) Table

```
        USE [HDA]
    GO

    /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Factions]    Script Date: 05/15/2014 02:42:16 ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO

    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Factions](
        [ID] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
        [Color] [nvarchar](5) NOT NULL,
        [Description] [ntext] NULL,
        [TS] [timestamp] NULL,
        [CreationDate] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_Factions] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [ID] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Factions] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__Factions__Creati__4D5F7D71]  DEFAULT (sysdatetime()) FOR [CreationDate]
    GO
```

Comment: Show you actual table structures (don't need to show ALL the fields, just the PKs and fields involved in the FKs)

Comment: Would it be better to attack it from a one to many relationship middle table. i.e. have a Characters_Factions table (CharacterId,FactionId). That way you could enforce a mutual integrity on the Factions (i.e. Character cannot belong to the same Faction more than one) and also gives you the flexibility to have a character belonging to more than 2 Factions in the future (as many as you want). Then there will be only one foreign key to Faction, non-unique on Character_Faction table

Comment: @Marc B: I have scripted the 2 tables don't know if those scripts will do.

Comment: @OJay: Don't know why I haven't thought of that before. But I was hoping, for the sake of knowledge, could it be done that way, I mean having 2 foreign keys that reference the same primary key, with null on delete and cascade on update ?

Comment: I personally wouldn't per-sue that as an option. Having two columns like [Fac1] and [Fac2] just screams to me normalization, i.e. having a separate table. I think as far as is it possible, I think the error indicates that it is not. Now I would also ask exactly what are you wanting to happen. When a Faction is deleted, then set all the characters references to that Faction to null. Is that what you are after. Should Id on Faction be an Identity Field?, so you wouldn't need on update cascade anyway? You could also manually implement a trigger on Faction to update/delete, so many options...

Comment: Are wanting to do the same thing with [Grp1] and [Grp2] ?

Comment: Yes, they follow the same concept of factions but there isn't too much groups (about 5~6) I will fill them manually as they are limited. Do you think this isn't a good option ?